# WebView Android 5 doesn't open links with target=_blank

Tags: android, webview

I recently detected an issue what I can only reproduce with a Samsung Galaxy S5 and Android 5.x (not with a HTC One, Android 5.x).

When opening a link in a WebView (target=_blank), then nothing happens. I can see an exception in the Logcat output, but the WebView WebViewClient Method `shouldOverrideUrlLoading` is never called (There I create an intent what opens the url).

[image: The error]

My current workaround is to remove the target=_blank from all links - but does anyone knows if this is a Bug or a normal behaviour and I've set something wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Having the same issue. I read somewhere it is a bug but none of the workarounds actually work for me.